# Validating hostnames/ip addresses in Java

Tags: java, validation, url, hostname

I'm working on a Java web app which has a form with individual "Protocol", "Hostname", and "Port" fields. I found that some people mistakenly include the protocol or port in the hostname. So I want to show an "Invalid hostname" if the hostname contains anything other than the hostname (or an IP address).

Currently, I'm using a `URL` object (initialized with `"http://" + hostname`) and checking that it does not throw an invalid URL exception and doesn not have a port or path.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Describe each valid input with an appropriate regexp, filter input (depends on the UI framework).

Comment: I think regex is what you are looking for.

Comment: You may want to reconsider your UI / UX.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès The issue with regexps is that I don't want to block cases like ipv6 IPs, international URLs, etc. My regex skills and internet specification familiarity are not up to the task, and I could not find an official/well-tested one anywhere.

Comment: @KasraFerdowsi At least consider "negative" filtering: catch input that contains protocol... Regexp skills are not so hard, what is hard is to specify what your valid/invalid inputs could be.